# Private social network suitable for companies inner culture development

Tags: web-apps, social-networks, enterprise-portal

My company is growing and it's becoming:

- difficult to remember all the names and personal features
- difficult to find out who among the employees in the entire company or specific team have certain experience with specific techs
- impossible to introduce each existing employee to new employees each time
- impossible to keep up with all the personal changes that are happening in employees lifes

So, I'm looking for some kind of social network (hosted or self-hosted), that can be isolated from everyone else, besides my employees.

List of desirable features can be quite long, so I'll just stop right here, because I haven't seen such services at all. Did you?

Comment: Have you thought about offering a fairly standard UBB style forum on your Intranet?

Answer (score 1):

You can get [Yammer](https://products.office.com/en-gb/yammer/yammer-overview) from Microsoft.  It's designed as a business internal social network which is available with desktop, web, and mobile clients so people can keep up-to-date, and update others from anywhere.

You can create groups to separate departments, and it comes with the typical social network features such as file uploading and direct chat.

If you are an Office 365 subscriber, you may already have htis as part of your subscription

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're looking for something more skills-targetted, but there's a general purpose one called [Elgg](https://elgg.org/) that I've installed before.  It lets users organize into groups, create fairly detailed profiles, create long- or short-form posts, share files, etc.  I haven't tried to use it for what you're talking about, but it might check a lot of the boxes.  You can host it yourself or the list a number of [hosting providers](https://elgg.org/about/hosting)

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal Social](https://www.drupal.org/project/social) or [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) gives you the opportunity to construct a suitable collaboration/community site which can be hosted or self-hosted. It also gives you the added benefit of adding more features as you grow, by using some of the existing drupal modules e.g. search_api, ldap, webform, etc.

The other alternatives are:

- Explore the use of LinkedIn to create a group only open to only your employees.
- Use an opensource CRM in-house e.g. SuiteCRM